# Normalize Bessel filter

Tags: lowpass-filter, transfer-function, normalization

I am applying a low pass filter to my signal and I should make sure the transfer function of my filter is one. How can I normalize my filter?
I am learning about filters and I appreciate any help.

```
%lowpass filter  
sig = MY SIGNAL;
sig_length = 5000001;                         % my signal length
fs  = 10000e9                                 % sampling rate
fc  = 3e9;                                    % cutt off frequency
order = 4; 
wo = 2*pi*fc;
[z,p,k] = besself(order, wo,'low');           % zero, pole and gain form
% Convert to digital fileter
[zd,pd,kd] = bilinear(z,p,k,fs*1e9);          % z-domain zero/pole/gain
[sos,g] = zp2sos(zd,pd,kd);                   % convert to second order section 
filteredSignal = filtfilt(sos, g, sig);
```

Comment: Just in case you don't know, that will no longer be a Bessel filter after the bilinear transformation. If linear phase IIR is what you're after then you need the Thiran filter.

Comment: Yes, my filter should have a linear phase. Would you please explain a little bit what you mean it is no longer a Bessel filter? Thanks

Comment: Search for "*recursive digital filters with maximaly flat group delay*" by Jean-Pierre Thiran. You'll see that the bilinear transform distorts the linear phase of the Bessel filter and, if you need a linear phase IIR, you need to derive it in digital domain. You'll end up with Gaussian hypergeometric functions -- this is the Thiran filter.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Thank you for your help. What if my Bessel filter shows linear phase in my bandwidth of interest? should I have to use Thiran?

Comment: I don't understand this part: "*what if ...*". Either it does, or it doesn't. And whether it does or not, it's up to you to know what you want. But a Bessel that has been transformed into the digital domain will **not** have a linear phase. And if you only care about a "bandwidth of interest", then you may as well choose a Cauer/elliptic with 10x the bandwidth. It doesn't make sense. Make up your mind about what you want. Either way, by now it sounds like you should ask a new question.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Obtaining the Steady State Gain from a SOS Filter**

As you can see, the filter is already normalized, since the Steady State response against a Unitary Step is one ([ref.](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/tf2sos.html)).

You can simply check by using an unary step:

```
%% Lowpass Filter Gain from Response
x=[0;ones(50000,1)];
lx=50001;df=10000;xdf=10;n=4;
[z,p,k]=besself(n,2*pi*xdf,'low'); 
[zd,pd,kd]=bilinear(z,p,k,df*1);   
[sos,g]=zp2sos(zd,pd,kd);         
xf=filtfilt(sos,g,x);
plot([x xf]);
k=xf(end)
```

Or by calculating the gain from the Zeros, Poles and Gain

```
%% Lowpass Filter Gain from Transfer Function
n=size(sos,2)/2
m=size(sos,1)
k=g;
for i=1:m
    k=k*sum(sos(i,1:n))/sum(sos(i,(1:n)+n));
end
k
```

In both cases, the result is $k=1$.

```
k =
    1.0000
```

Comment: Or simpler: use the gain at DC, which will be the sum of the coefficients of the numerator divided by the sum of the coefficients of the denominator.

Comment: The *for* cycle intends to do so, but as you say, the *for* is not required.

Comment: Yes, but what I meant was that there's no need to complicate with `sos()` from `[z,p,k]`, when you can use directly `[a,b]=besself(,'z')` and then `sum(a)/sum(b)`. But maybe OP has that way imposed.

Comment: @Brethlosze Thank you so much for your help

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen So the filter is normalized but based on your first comment its phase is not linear? Am I right? I should use yours suggested filter to get linear phase?